# Adding/Removing Cocoon Nested Fields

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I'm using the awesome gem Cocoon to generate nested fields based on a "length" value that the user can select.  My problem is that I need to find a way to check how many nested fields have already been added to the form, and then only add ones that are not in the form currently.  For example:

A user has the length value set at 2, there are 2 sets of nested fields form them to work with.  Now the user wants to change their value to 3, this is where I run into difficulty.  I'm not entirely sure how to add/remove the fields based on the changed value, without just removing all the fields and re-running the nested fields insertion.  Here is some code for reference:

`HTML`

```
<div class="row px-md-4">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column pb-3">
      <h2 class="f-500 dark_grey_text pt-3" style="font-size:1.8em;">Itinerary Details</h2>
      <p class="f-300">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 py-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <h6>Set your length</h6>
      <%= f.number_field :length, placeholder:"How many days is your adventure?", value: number_with_precision(f.object.length, precision: 2), step: 1, class: 'stepper_navtext form-control', id: 'length' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-12 py-3">
    <div class="form-row mb-3" id="days">
      <div class="nav nav-pills" id="tab-menu" role="tablist">

      </div>

      <div class="tab-content" id="itinerary-tab-content">

      </div>

        <div id='itineraries' class='w-100 itineraries'>
          <%= f.fields_for :itineraries do |itinerary| %>
            <%= render 'adventure/listings/forms/itinerary_fields', :f => itinerary %>
          <% end %>
          <div class='links'>
            <%= link_to_add_association 'add day', f, :itineraries, partial: 'adventure/listings/forms/itinerary_fields', class:"d-none" %>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`JS`

```
$('#length').on('focusin', function(){
    console.log("Saving value " + $(this).val());
    $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
});

$( "#length" ).change(function() {

      var prev = $(this).data('val');
      var current = $(this).val();
      console.log("Prev value " + prev);
      console.log("New value " + current);

      $('#tab-menu').empty();

      $('.nested-fields').remove();

      let days = $('#length').val();
      var i;
      var counter = current - prev;
      console.log('The difference is' + counter);
      var text_max = 40;

      for (i = 0; i < days; i++) {
        var new_id;
        $(".links").find(">:first-child").trigger("click");
      }  ...
```

The only solution I've found is to clear all fields from the form, and regenerate the clicks on the add association button from Cocoon.  It all seems a hacky to me and I don't think I'm doing this the right way :/.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: I have turbolinks off for the sections affected.  I think my biggest problem is getting around the concept of how what math/code block could be used to check the existing fields, and only add/remove based on the changed values difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close imho, so I am wondering what is holding you back to actually finding the solution. So let me first explain in pseudo-code (this always helps me when some problem seems insurmountable) :

- when the length changes
- check how the length changed
- if length increased: add the fields
- if it decreased: remove the fields from the back

So in code, that could look like

```
$( "#length" ).change(function() 
  var prev = $(this).data('val');
  var current = $(this).val();

  if (current > prev) {
    var days_to_add = current - prev; 
    for (i = 0; i < days_to_add; i++) {
      $(".links").find(">:first-child").trigger("click");
    }  
  } else {
    var days_to_remove = prev - current; 
    for (i = 0; i < days_to_remove; i++) {
      $('#itineraries .nested-fields').last().remove();  
    }  
  }
```

I am not entirely sure if your `prev` / `current` is set correctly, unless you are setting `data('val')`, but since `prev` is just the currently visible days, you also as well do something like:

```
var prev = $("#itineraries .nested-fields:visible').length; 
var current = $this.val();
```

(why use `:visible`? because if you also allow to remove-fields while editing we have to "hide" the field instead of just remove them)

This reminds me: if you do show the `link_to_remove_association` it is much better to click that, or if you add it as "hidden", because that will correct keep your form correct. This only applies if you also allow to edit existing forms, because in that case we need to keep the nested-child with a `_destroy` flag set, so rails can then destroy it when saving the form.

Comment: Thank you!!  This helped me immensely, especially the pseudo code portion tor really understand the steps I was trying to take.  I had to make a few adjustments as I'm placing each nested fields set into a tabs/panes Bootstrap setup, so they aren't visible by default.  I'm going to attempt the edit setups next and still need to read up on that process in the docs :).  Thank you again for making a fantastic gem and for helping the community so much!